# Best layout for form-style screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering if I am missing certain layout that I am not sure about that would be good for my use case

Usually I come across a form-style screen where it has the following

```
Label        Value
Label        Value
etc..
```

I can achieve this by doing root linear layout with nested linear layouts (best alignment). Or by doing constraint layout and linking everything together (but so much xml code to do, sometimes hard to follow).
I guess I can do this using table layout as well.

Is there a best practice for such style of screens?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with *Nezih Yılmaz*, In my opinions [constraintlayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) will work for you.

- Sure, you can have nested view groups using a linear layout but it may affect your performance (the more nested you go the slower your layout might me).
- Don't forget that `constraintlayout` is meant to be responsive - you will only have to make one layout and it will be responsive to every screen size.

*but so much xml code to do*, **then don't**:

You can work from the design tab to build your layout instead of writing your XML, it will save you a lot of time, for example, you can do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView11"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView12"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView13"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Label"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView14"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Value"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView10"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Value"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView11"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Value"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView12"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Value"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView13"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Value"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView14"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Value"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Your layout will look like this:**

[image]

If you really want to control your views while using ConstraintLayout you can use it with with [guidelines](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html) and [Chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) to support different screen sizes.

You can also control the size of your views in percents using those attributes:

```
 app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.x"
 app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.x"
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically constraintlayout is best to use for such screens but given layout example is relatively simple so you can go with whichever viewgroup you are more comfortable with.

Constraintlayouts flat hierarchy benefits are better seen 
and understood when you refactor a complex layout which contains even more nesting.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is most forms on Android (especially following [design guidelines](https://material.io/) look like this [Material Text Input](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/), so your label/value layout might look a little out of place on Android, but if it works for your use case then it works. These edit texts have floating labels or hints that are more modern than a table.

Check out this too text-fields
https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#
[image: Text Fields]

The best parent layout is going to be what works best for you. But as others have said, ConstraintLayout is the most efficient and in my opinion, the most effective.

With that being said it is still recommended to

**"To create a material text field, add a TextInputLayout to your XML layout and a TextInputEditText as a direct child."**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text">

  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Or you can just use an edit text inside your parent layout

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/plain_text_input"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:hint="@string/hint_text"
     android:inputType="text"/>
```